# Did Tarkin know Darth Vader's previous identity?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, the-force, a-new-hope

In *A New Hope*, Grand Moff Tarkin and Vader exchange the following words:

> **VADER** Don't underestimate the Force.
>
> **TARKIN:** The Jedi are extinct. Their fire has gone out of the universe. You, my friend, are all that's left of their religion.

**Did Tarkin know that Vader was once**

> **the Jedi Anakin Skywalker?**

**Or had "Jedi" become a catch-all term for Force users, good or evil, by this point in time?**

Comment: SPOILERS IN THE TITLE PRAXIS!!!!!

Comment: @MacCooper : Only for rand al'thor!  ;-)

Comment: Re edit : I was kidding. who doesn't know?

Comment: From "Tarkin" - "*Sidious assumed that Tarkin had puzzled out that Vader had once been Anakin Skywalker, under whom Tarkin had served during the war. Tarkin may also have determined that Vader was a Sith. If so, it followed that he accepted that Sidious was Vader’s dark side Master. But Tarkin’s intuitions were important only in the sense that he never revealed them and never allowed them to interfere with his own ambitions."*

Comment: @Richard : Sounds like the start of an answer.  :-)

Comment: @Praxis Not even! ;-) Happy New Year btw :-)

Comment: @randal'thor : Hehe.  Happy New Year to you too! :-)

Comment: if we're trying to block the spoiler, it's in the body of the question too ^^

Comment: @MacCooper : I think it's common knowledge --- there are tons and tons of questions on SFF which openly talk about Vader being Anakin.  I wouldn't worry about it.  :-)

Comment: @Praxis, no i agree i dont think it should be spoilered -- but if the title is i figure it should all be?

Comment: @MacCooper : Fair point.  I'll spoiler the body too.  Thanks.  :-)

Comment: @Praxis - sorry, this is a Duplicate. http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/92715/976 and http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/83107/976

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the SW novel "[Tarkin](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tarkin_(novel))", he had very (very) strong suspicions but he kept them largely to himself:

> *Later, observing the rapport the Dark Lord shared with the
>   stormtroopers who supported him, and the technique he displayed in
>   wielding his crimson lightsaber, Tarkin grew more and more convinced
>   that his suspicions were right. Vader might very well be Jedi Knight
>   Anakin Skywalker, whom Tarkin had fought beside during the Clone Wars,
>   and for whom he had developed a grudging appreciation.*

[later]

> *Sidious assumed that Tarkin had puzzled out that Vader had once been
>   Anakin Skywalker, under whom Tarkin had served during the war. Tarkin
>   may also have determined that Vader was a Sith. If so, it followed
>   that he accepted that Sidious was Vader’s dark side Master. But
>   Tarkin’s intuitions were important only in the sense that he never
>   revealed them and never allowed them to interfere with his own
>   ambitions.*

He made a few half-hearted attempts to confirm whether it was Anakin behind the mask, but didn't push the issue:

> *“If we aren’t willing to do whatever is required,” he said finally,
>   “then we risk losing what we have been mandated to protect.”*
>
> *The remark paraphrased something Skywalker had said to him following
>   the Citadel rescue. But it got no reaction from Vader beyond his
>   saying, “You misunderstand, Governor. As I said, we need to gather all
>   of them in our net.”*

Comment: Duplicate? http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/92715/976 and http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/83107/976 ?

Comment: @DVK - Dunno. I don't vote on stuff.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't trying to tempt you to stike-break :)